# Get posts having multiple categories WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to list posts by category. It is working fine in case of single category. But when there are multiple categories of a post, it only gets the first category and not the others. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to list all categories in a page and list posts under that? You better ask in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, but it works now. 

Comment: So how did you get it to work? Would you mind sharing your solution for others to benefit from?

Answer (score 1):

According with the WP documentation, you can filter by multiples categories. This the link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

```html
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '2,6,17,38' ) );

$query_v2 = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'staff,news' ) );
```

Regards,
Ed.